# Generator function inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, generator

i have class base component and i want to declare inside it a generator function for an api call. I must not use fetch.then. Here is my code

```
class SearchField extends React.Component {

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearSearchState();
  }

  handleOnFocus() {
    function* focus(){
      yield call(request, 'POST', URL, BODY)
     }
  }

  handleOnBlur() {
    this.props.handleOnBlur();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id={this.props.searchFieldId}
          type="text"
          value={this.props.value || ''}
          placeholder={this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: this.props.placeholder })}
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.props.handleOnChange(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="text"
          onFocus={this.props.handleOnFocus}
          onBlur={this.props.handleOnBlur}
        />
        <button
          className="clear"
          onClick={this.props.clearFieldValue}
          style={{ display: this.props.clearButtonVisible ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this possible to do this in my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is possible to have (and call) generator functions in (from) the React Component. I think it should work if you pull out generator function declaration from the handleOnFocus method and then invoke it from the handleOnFocus method:

```
  *focus() {
    yield call(request, "POST", URL, BODY);
  }

  handleOnFocus = () => {
    this.focus()._invoke();
  };
```

I managed to call the focus (generator) function and log to the console, you can take a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/v63r54pqq3

Comment: the _invoke() is plain javascript or i must import something?

Comment: I think it is, I didn't import anything extra.. But if that's not working, can you try this: 

 ` *focus() {
    yield call(request, "POST", URL, BODY);
  }

  handleOnFocus = () => {
    let focus = this.focus();
    focus.next();
  };`

I've edited sandbox too: https://codesandbox.io/s/v63r54pqq3